# useEffect cleanup function not working in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm trying to get the token from Expo's SecureStore and then dispatch an action.

I'm using useEffect so that I can check if there is a token I can use when the component is first rendered.

```
useEffect(() => {
let mounted = true;

SecureStore.getItemAsync('token').then((token) =>
  token ? dispatch({ type: 'signin', payload: token }) : null
);

return () => (mounted = false);
}, []);
```

However, I can't get rid of:

> Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is
> a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in  your application. To fix,
> cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup
> function

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnuWT.png)

More code as requested:

```
import React, { useReducer, createContext, useEffect } from 
'react';
import * as SecureStore from 'expo-secure-store';
import forumApi from '../api/forumApi';

export const Context = createContext();

const reducer = (state, action) => {
switch (action.type) {
case ('signup', 'signin'):
  return { ...state, token: action.payload };
case 'error': {
  return { token: undefined, errorMessage: action.payload };
}
default:
  return state;
 }
};

const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, {
token: undefined,
errorMessage: '',
 });

useEffect(() => {
let mounted = true;

const runAsync = async () =>
  await SecureStore.getItemAsync('token').then((token) =>
    token ? dispatch({ type: 'signin', payload: token }) : null
  );

runAsync();

return () => (mounted = false);
}, []);

const signup = async (fullName, email, password, passwordConfirm) 
=> {
try {
  const res = await forumApi.post('/api/v1/users/signup', {
    fullName,
    email,
    password,
    passwordConfirm,
  });

  const { token } = res.data;
  await SecureStore.setItemAsync('token', token);
  dispatch({ type: 'signup', payload: token });
} catch (err) {
  dispatch({
    type: 'error',
    payload: 'We could not register you. Please try with 
 different email.',
  });
 }
 };

 const signin = async (email, password) => {
 try {
  const res = await forumApi.post('/api/v1/users/signin', {
    email,
    password,
  });

  const { token } = res.data;
  await SecureStore.setItemAsync('token', token);
  dispatch({ type: 'signin', payload: token });
} catch (err) {
  dispatch({
    type: 'error',
    payload: 'We could not log you in. Please try again.',
  });
 }
 };

const signinGoogle = async (token, fullName, email, photo) => {
try {
  const res = await forumApi.post('/api/v1/users/auth/google', {
    fullName,
    email,
    photo,
  });

  await SecureStore.setItemAsync('token', token);
  dispatch({ type: 'signup', payload: token });
} catch (err) {
  dispatch({
    type: 'error',
    payload: 'We could not register you. Please try with different email.',
  });
}
};

return (
<Context.Provider
  value={{ state, signup, signin, signinGoogle, tryLocalSignin }}
>
  {children}
</Context.Provider>
 );
 };

export default AuthProvider;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@florian22 so it appears you are attempting to update the state on the provider level.  In order to update the state of a context you must be inside the provider.  The useEffect must be on an inner node.

See example:

```js
const App = ({children}) => {

    useEffect(() => {
     const runAsync = async () => {
     const token = await SecureStore.getItemAsync('token');

     if(token) dispatch({ type: 'signin', payload: token });
     }

     runAsync();
     }, []);

  return (<View>{children}</View>);
  }

const MainApp = ({children}) => {

return (
<AuthProvider>
 <App>
  {children}
 </App>
</AuthProvider>
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the same issues. I'm using then syntax so that's why I'm not awaiting. I'm using the mounted variable so that I can clear subscriptions and asynchronous tasks. That's what it says, i've attached a screenshot

Comment: @florian22 can you post all your code on the page for context please?  Also, please see my revises code if you have not seen it.  Running your method async and awaiting it should prevent it from attempting to update an unmounted component.

Comment: Unfortunately, running it async then awaiting not working. I've added the all the code above

Comment: @florian22 please see updated code.  You can only update your state inside the AuthProvider.  Can't be done on the same level.

Comment: I see. I tweaked the code and get no more errors now. Thanks!

Comment: @florian22 please mark as answer if this fixed your issue thanks.

Comment: This is the first time I have asked a question here. Thanks for letting me know. Enjoy your evening

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for using `mounted` variable. This is enough

```
useEffect(() => {
  SecureStore.getItemAsync("token").then((token) =>
    token ? dispatch({ type: "signin", payload: token }) : null
  );
}, []);
```

Comment: Right, that's was my initial guess, but React Native is yelling at me saying that all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks should be cleared